# Chrome extensions how to remove devtools network added listener

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

i use this code to add a listener to get all request and the reponse body:
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(this.networkListener.bind(this));
but how can i remove this listener!

Answer (score 1):

All events in chrome extensions have `removeListener` and a few other methods, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-Event) for more info, so you can remove it as usual:

1. store the **actual** function reference, meaning `this.networkListener.bind(this)`

   ```js
   this.networkListenerBound = this.networkListener.bind(this);
   chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(this.networkListenerBound);
   ```
2. use that reference in `removeListener`

   ```js
   chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.removeListener(this.networkListenerBound);
   ```

Comment: thank you very much! the key point is store the actual function reference,